# I have Akamai pointing to a WordPress installation with a different URL. Is there a way to make WordPress use this for link generation?

Tags: permalinks, urls

I have a WordPress website at, lets say, `http://a.domain`. For reasons beyond me, I needed `http://b` to be the URL and the way they found was to put Akamai in front of the website.

It works, as I can access the website at `http://b`. However, all the permalinks are generated as `http://a.domain/link` instead of `http://b/link`, and if I change `WP_HOME` to `http://b` it enters a redirection loop.

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: Welcome to WordPress development! Seems something is misconfigured in this setup. So they use Akamai only to display the site at another URL? Then I'd switch off Akamai and change `WP_HOME` again. Or is there something custom in your `.htaccess` going on?

Comment: This URL stuff is related to the infrastructure here... Nothing I can really control unfortunately :/